# Test difference between two transition matrices (probabilities of default)

Tags: probability, markov-chains, transition-matrix, risk-assessment

Recently, at work, I developed a project to estimate probabilities of default (PDs) using Markov Chains. We have a portafolio of loans classified in an internal rating (ratings from "Bucket" 1 to 10, where bucket10 is the state of default). The state of default is absorbent and the higher the Bucket, the higher the PD for a loan.

First, I estimated a monthly transition matrix, $M_{monthly}$, with the observed monthly transitions between buckets in a determined period. Then, to get annual PDs, I elevated to the 12 power this matrix.

However, my boss asked to make a yearly transtition matrix, $M_{yearly}$, (using observed YEARLY transitions between buckets) to compare it to $M_{monthly}^{12}$.

My question is, how can I compare them and tell if they are statistically similar? Do I compare all the entries of the matrices or only the last column of the matrices (the columns of the PDs)?

I have looked to different norms and the goodness-of-fit $X^2$ but Im not sure which is the most aproppiate test I can use.

I'll appreciate your help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not really relevant to the question you asked, but I might suspect there may be significant seasonal effects: rather than a single $M_{monthly}$, you might find significantly different transition matrices for different months.  Of course much modeling based on previous years will be useless in this year of Covid-19.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence is a measure of the difference between densities. You could bootstrap a test statistic for whether the divergence between the two distributions is significantly different from zero (take random subsamples of the data, compute the two matrices, compute the KL divergence, do this over and over thousands of times, then see if 0 is in the 90/95/99/$\alpha$-confidence interval).

Comment: @RobertIsrael I see your point. My $M_{monthly}$ is an “average” transition matrix from the transition matrices for each month. However, I tested the time homogeneity of the chain and it was passed (using two different tests). Of course, this year will be useless due to Covid. Anyway, a matrix for this year may be used as an extreme pessimist scenario for future modeling.

Comment: @Renard thanks a lot I think it will be really useful. However, do you know if there is any conventional threshold to determine the results of the divergence? I mean, my bosses are not that into the mathematical side, thus, explaining what the **information gain** is may be confusing and rather unpractical.